# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement SOLR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, solr

I want to get data from a Solr server, using Angular (and put result in a table).

I wrote my Angular controller and I used $http. Like this:

```
var myApp_1 = angular.module('myApp_1', []);
myApp_1.controller('RequestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,  $http){

$scope.title = {};
$scope.response = {};

var url = "http://10.1.1.1:8983/solr/testCore/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&callback=jsonp_callback";

$http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function (data){
        console.log(data.response);
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log('Error');
    });

}]);
```

But it gave me the console message: **SyntaxError: missing ; before statement.** 
I saw that the error came from the shape of the server answer; which is:

```
{"responseHeader":
    {"status":0,"QTime":1,"params":
    {"q":"*:*","callback":"jsonp_callback","wt":"json"}},
    "response":{"numFound":5,"start":0,"docs":[                                              
        {"id":"123456789",
         "title":["45e"],
         "_version_":1506864900238999552},
        {"id":"12",
         "title":["aeuirs"],
         "_version_":1506865190152437760}
]}}
```

(I indent it here because it was pretty illegible, but not to much because it is difficult with the StackO. editor).

I can’t write &wt=jsonp in my url (it doesn’t work).

Firebug said me that the error is after the "responseHeader": apparently, it should be a ; instead of a :

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct argument name should be `&json.wrf=callback` (or whatever callback name you want/need - the important thing is `json.wrf`).

[JSON Specific Parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON#JSON_specific_parameters)

> **json.wrf=function** - adds a wrapper-function around the JSON response, useful in AJAX with dynamic script tags for specifying a JavaScript callback function.

Comment: Ok, now Firebug says me: ReferenceError: callback is not defined callback({. Nevertheless, I saw that many people use callback=JSON_CALLBACK. But, @MatsLindh, I don’t understand so much things in the link you left.

Comment: @Carapatte You have to use the name that Angular expects - read the jsonp docs for Angular - might be ? - it might append its own. jsonp works by wrapping the data in a function name provided by you or your library, and giving access to the data that way. That function name has to be the one the library expects.

Comment: Finally, I decide to use the $http.get method by authorising CORS (explained here opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/03/26/…) Thanks for your help :) …maybe I have to write it in an answer ?

Comment: Hi @Chènevis, could you post full url(opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/03/26/…). I am facing same issue. Its giving 404

Comment: I am sorry because I do not work on this task anymore, it was in my last office…I think I have solved the problem by doing it all in JAVA